Out of Memory Error when loading images in DataGridView
I am trying to load some 300 small scaled images, each in a DataGridViewImageCell of a DataGridViewControl and I run into an Out of Memory error.
I have seen that someone used to have the same kind of issue a while back ("System out of memory exception" when try to load images in datagridview (VB Net)) but can't seem to figure out how this could work.
Used this simple code in the Form_Load event of a quick test app like this:
sDir = IO.Directory.GetFiles(sPath, "*.jpg")
For Each s In sDir
   Dim img as image

   img = Image.FromFile(s)
   img = ScaleImage(img, 100, 100)
   row = Dgv.Rows(Dgv.Rows.Add)
   row.Cells(0).Value = img
   row.Cells(1).Value = s
 Next

with a ScaleImage function being:
Public Function ScaleImage(OldImage As Image, TargetHeight As Integer, TargetWidth As Integer) As System.Drawing.Image
    Dim NewWidth As Integer = TargetWidth
    Dim NewHeight As Integer

    If OldImage.Width <> 0 Then
        NewHeight = NewWidth / OldImage.Width * OldImage.Height

        If NewHeight > TargetHeight Then
            NewHeight = TargetHeight
            NewWidth = NewHeight / OldImage.Height * OldImage.Width
        End If
        If NewWidth > TargetWidth Then
            NewWidth = TargetWidth
            NewHeight = NewWidth / OldImage.Width * OldImage.Height
        End If

        Return New Bitmap(OldImage, NewWidth, NewHeight)
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function

The memory overflow occurs randomly after about 185 images which use around 180Mb, out of 335 images.
This is using VS2022 and a 32 bits application.
I tried replacing all images with a default 16x16 px resource icon and display is ok...
What am I doing wrong here?
Any help would be appreciated

You can show respect for those who might help you by ensuring the code is formatted properly, and not indented extra to the right more than is needed to get syntax highlighting.

But I suspect (not sure, so just a comment) what's happening in is the old (pre-resize) images are garbage collected correctly and the memory is available to the OS and your program, but the virtual address space they used in your program is not reclaimed. When the virtual address table runs out, this presents as an OutOfMemoryException.

@Joel Coehoorn: I am sorry but I am not very familiar with the StackOverflow rules and did try my best to format my code. Will try to better next time.

One more question. When you say there are 185 images which use around 180Mb, is that 180Mb each, or 180Mb in total? I suspect total, but it's useful to be certain around this kind of thing.

185 images which use around 180Mb: are you referring to the combined sizes of the files, or the memory usage when those images are decompressed? I assume the former. If you don't dispose of the source images, you kill your app very quickly. Try just replacing the image generation with Using img as image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(s)), true, false) dim scaledImage = ScaleImage(img, 100, 100) '[...] the rest End Using -- Your scaling procedure is weird

Side note: the resized images are better handled using a collection (e.g., a List(Of Bitmap)), so disposing of the scaled images, when not needed anymore, becomes easier; or even better, a class object that stores the Image and its path, then use a collection of these class objects as the DataSource of your DataGridView

@Joel and Jimi: yes, 180Mb represent the total size of images.
I ´ll try to follow your recommendation with Using-End Using and/or with a List(Of or a class.
Thank you both

OK. Using your advices seem to make it work, that is, using both a list of bitmaps and using "Using img as Image" etc.. The only drawback is that it is awfully slow and just unacceptable from a timing standpoint. Sounds like I'll have to find another way to display this list of images...Thanks to you both.
